# Read and applied any advice but can't pass the login page with cURL in php

Tags: asp.net, authentication, curl, redirect

I've used all the necessary cURL options (CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION) to get cURL pass the login page but with no luck. I'm trying to pass the login on http://apps.allogalogistics.ro and get some records on another page. The login page has a redirect.

I make a POST req on the login page and I save the cookies in a cookies.txt with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE. I see that after the POST req another GET req is initiated in the login process. I tried everything I read but all I can see from cURL is the login page with the username/password empty (not logged) even if the response is 200 OK.

```
<?php
$url = "http://apps.allogalogistics.ro";

$ckfile  = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookies1.txt';
$logfile  = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';

$username = "XXXX";
$password = "YYYY";

$f = fopen($logfile, 'w'); 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); //"http://apps.allogalogistics.ro/main/Desktop"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);



/* --- Input fields in the login page ----
txtRedirect: /main/Desktop
txtPlatform: Desktop
txtLogonPath: 
redirectTo: 
rowid: 
txtOrganization: main
txtUserName: XXXX
txtPassword: YYYY
ckRememberMe: on
------------------*/

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['language'] = "";
$postfields['platform'] = "desktop";
$postfields['txtUserName'] = rawurlencode($username);
$postfields['txtPassword'] = rawurlencode($password);
$postfields['txtRedirect'] = rawurlencode('/main/Desktop');
$postfields['txtPlatform'] = "Desktop";
$postfields['txtLogonPath'] = "";
$postfields['redirectTo'] = "";
$postfields['rowid'] = "";
$postfields['txtOrganization'] = "main";
$postfields['ckRememberMe'] = "on"; //checked
//$postfields['btnLogin'] = "Autentificare";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

$ret = curl_exec($ch); 

$errors = curl_error($ch);
$details = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($errors);
var_dump($details);

curl_close($ch);

fclose($f);

var_dump($ret);

?>
```

Expected to get passed the login page and the session maintained to get from another page some records.

Comment: I also observed that .ASPXAUTH cookie is not being returned. I do have the .ASP.NET_SessionID but not the .ASPXAUTH cookie.
In Chrome Network I noticed that I can see the .ASPXAUTH cookie value in the headers but I can't get my cURL script to return this cookie.

Comment: I made curl not change the method (POST--> GET) when it follows the redirect; for this I used curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3) and it works  (now it's POST--->POST) but I obtained the same result as before (not logged). Pls I really need to resolve this.

Comment: can anybody give me an advice?